# Ubuntu 15.04 keeps crashing randomly

Tags: 15.04, crash

My ubuntu 15.04 laptop keeps crashing at random intervals, how will I go about fixing this? The emergency mode appears on the screen, and then automatically reboots, thus resulting in loss of data.

Comment: Please be more specific! No one can help you without details...

Comment: How can we help you if we don't know what you have? Did you install anything recently? What model computer do you have? Does the computer get hot?

Comment: I have a Dell Inspiron N5010, Team Viewer is the most recently installed, and the computer does not get hot.